# Compare versions in mySql

Tags: mysql, compare, version

I save software and their versions in a table. The version column is varchar(254) and contains versions like 2.0.0.45 I want to sort and compare the versions in mysql. I have an idea that one day I might have a version with a number greater than 255 (2.0.0.999) so the suggestion to treat the version as an IP and compare that way is not going to work.

What is the simplest way to do a version comparison in mySQL?

Comment: Here are similar questions for 4 group version numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104142/sql-compare-version-string-w-x-y-z-in-mysql and 3 group version numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709452/how-to-compare-version-string-x-y-z-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 4 seperate columns like

```
release
major
minor
build
```

or something like that.

Using seperate columns is way easier to query and faster too. And you don't need any string manipulation functions to split up your version into their parts.

Comment: I thought of that but if I have to do so much work I might just as well write a function that returns true or false - just as much work?

Comment: using seperate columns is way easier to query and faster too. You don't need any string manipulation functions to split up your version into their parts.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that it assumes you have at most `x=4` components in the version number. What about latex version `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17`? Okay, `x=5`would do here. But anyone can come up with a new software that has version numbers with `x+1` components, no matter how big you choose `x`.