# SQL: Compare Version string (W.X.Y.Z) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709452/how-to-compare-version-string-x-y-z-in-mysql) except I have 4 groups, not 3.

Is there a way to order by version strings with 4 groups in MySQL only?

Some of the sample versions are:

```
10.0.0.0
11.0.0.3
12.0.0.125
13.8.6.800
```

There will always only be 4 groups.

Comment: Do you know the maximum length of each *number*?

Comment: From left to right, the max length would be 2, 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uri's comment on using a UDF is likely best.  However, if you can't  here's a different approach:   it takes advantage of implicit casting using *1 and [substring_index function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) which "Return a substring from a string before the specified number of occurrences of the delimiter"

```
SELECT Version
FROM foo
order by 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 1 )*1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1)*1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -2 ),'.',1)*1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -1 )*1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dd1e/3/0)

additionally the values between the .'s can be of any length just as long as they are of numeric data type.

source found: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index in comments by name withheld user on March 22 2006 8:02pm

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately MySQL does not feature a split string function. However you can create a [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) for this, such as the one described in the following article:

- [MySQL Split String Function](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) by Federico Cargnelutti

With that function, you would be able to build your query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM   tbl ORDER BY
CAST(SPLIT_STR(version, '.', 1) AS INT),
CAST(SPLIT_STR(version, '.', 2) AS INT),
CAST(SPLIT_STR(version, '.', 3) AS INT),
CAST(SPLIT_STR(version, '.', 4) AS INT);
```