# Proper schema/query for 'X and above' entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

Sorry for the confusing title, couldn't think of a better one. Let me explain with an example. There are two tables, one has a list of operating systems and another contains list of different versions of those operating systems. The following picture will made it more clear.
[image]

I can get items that belongs/related to a particular os_version by doing a query against it like `select * from items where os_versions.id = 3`. However I also want to do a query like Android 3.0+, which will mean Android 3.0 and above so, this query will pull all items with os_version with ids 3,4,5 and 6 (please refer table). What's the best way to do it? Can it be done on db itself with some kind of changes in the table design or better to do it in the codes? right now I am maintaining an array to lookup which os_versions to pullup for a query with a +, but it appears messy. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: can you have a `version` column is os_versions and go `where version >= 3.0` ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to save the version as a string - you can save it as a number, and then query it using mathematical operators:

```
CREATE TABLE OperatingSystem (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    os VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE OS_Versions (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    os_id INT NOT NULL,
    os_version DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT os_id_fk FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES OperatingSystems (id)
);
```

To get all the androids above 3.0:

```
SELECT CONCAT(os, ' ', FORMAT(os_version, 1))
FROM   OperatingSystem os
JOIN   OS_Versions osv ON os.id = osv.os_id
```

Comment: How do I handle different types of versions? e.g, Android has versions like 2.2, 2.3, 2.2.3 (two dots), 4.1.2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in the query?

This function in PHP will do a version comparison, you could use it in a custom filter after running your query, perhaps just pulling all of that particular os_id first.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

Otherwise, this question may give you some ideas about how to handle it at the query level:

[How to compare version string ("x.y.z") in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709452/how-to-compare-version-string-x-y-z-in-mysql)